# How/where to create mongod.conf file?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, mongoose

I need to create a `mongod.conf` file but I'm having trouble with the **where** and **how**.

**Where:** Since the command to run the file is `mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf`, I understand I need to create the file in `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\etc`

**How:** When I right-click or open the path in Atom, I'm only given the option to create a folder. How can I override this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out!

It was related to admin privileges on my Windows computer.

I was able to create the file elsewhere and then move it to the path, where I was prompted to give admin permission. Wish I thought of this at some point during the past week when the struggle was real :P